# send-MailMessage not working

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am using the `send-MailMessage` cmdlet in PowerShell version 2 and it gives me a error.

I tried using all the options which were mentioned in the earlier posts and it didn't help me.

This is the command that I am using:

```
send-MailMessage -from "abc@gmail.com" -to "def@gmail.com" 
                 -subject "test" -body"test" -smtp "smtp.gmail.com"
```

I get an error:

> Send-MailMessage : The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated
>   e was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. l46sm12283804qgd.27 - gsmtp
>   At line:1 char:17
>   + send-MailMessage <<<<  -from "abc@gmail.com" -to "def@gmail.com" -subject "te
>   credential abc
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Se
>   ion
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage

I tried  using `UseSsl= true` and also by giving credentials and even then I was not able to send email. Could you let me know what I am missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use *gmail* you need SSL, I'am not sure you can use `Send-MailMessage` try this :

```
$emailSmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$emailSmtpServerPort = "587"
$emailSmtpUser = "yourlogin@gmail.com"
$emailSmtpPass = "yourPassword"

$emailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$emailMessage.From = "yourlogin@gmail.com"
$emailMessage.To.Add("YourSendTo@mail.com")
$emailMessage.Subject = "Small mail for a friend"
$emailMessage.IsBodyHtml = $true
$emailMessage.Body = @"
<p><strong>Hello me</strong>.</p>
<p>It seems to work</p>
<p>JP</p>
"@

$SMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient( $emailSmtpServer , $emailSmtpServerPort )
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential( $emailSmtpUser , $emailSmtpPass );

$SMTPClient.Send( $emailMessage )
```

---

Edited :

To use mail attachment please have a look [Sytem.Net.Mail.MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation. You need first to create an [Attachment](http://System.Net.Mail.Attachment) and then to add it to the MailMessage `Attacments` collection.

Comment: Thanks!!!it worked.Also could you let me know how I could add attachments to the same command send it in the email.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For those that come later, here is my two liner example, for the account "gmail-user@gmail.com". This can be scheduled.

```
$credentials = new-object Management.Automation.PSCredential “gmail-user@gmail.com”, (“gmail-user's password” | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)

Send-MailMessage -From "gmail-user@gmail.com" -to "someone-else@gmail.com" -Subject "Some subject"
-Body "Some body" -SmtpServer "smtp.gmail.com" -port 587 -UseSsl
-Credential $credentials -Attachments "C:\an-attachment.txt"
```

Comment: This only works if your mail server supports SSL (not to be confused with STARTTLS) on port 587.

Comment: Actually not...  UseSsl tells PowerShell to not do clear text...  what level of SSL negotiated is left open to defaults and custom configurations.  If the mail server requires SSL but also requires TLS 1.2 then simply setting -UseSsl isn't enough to avoid issues.

Comment: PowerShell 2.0 does not support `-Port` for `Send-MailMessage` yet.