# Send-MailMessage on PowerShell does not work

Tags: powershell, email

I have a big problem. For a school club I have to write a script which sends emails automatically. I decided to use PowerShell for that.

My Code:

```
Send-MailMessage –To "email@outlook.com" –Subject "Test E-Mail" –Body "FIRST EMAIL WITH POWERSHELL" –SmtpServer "smtp.gmail.com" –From "email@gmail.com"
```

My error code:

> Send-MailMessage: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client has not been authenticated. The server response was:
>   5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. o3sm51888528wrs.30 - gsmtp
>   In line: 1 character: 1
>   + Send-MailMessage -To "email@outlook.com" Subject "Test E-Mail" -Bod ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo: InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient: SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId: SmtpException, Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage

And if I write

```
–SmtpServer "gsmtp.gmail.com"
```

the error code is:

> Send-MailMessage : The connection to the remote server cannot be established. 
>   In line:1 character:1 
>   + Send-MailMessage -To "email@outlook.com"; -Subject "Test E-Mail"; -Bod . . . 
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
>   + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (System. Net. Mail. SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpException 
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft. PowerShell. Commands. SendMailMessage

Do you know what´s the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [send-MailMessage not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875471/send-mailmessage-not-working)

Comment: As an aside: [`Send-MailMessage`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage) is considered _obsolete_, because it "does not guarantee secure connections to SMTP servers". If that isn't a concern in a given case, it still works and is unlikely to ever be _removed_, given PowerShell's commitment to backward compatibility. One modern alternative is the third-party [`Send-MailKitMessage`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Send-MailKitMessage) cmdlet, which builds on the third-party [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you will need to enable "less secure apps" in your Google account settings.
To do so, click on the [following link](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps), then set the **Allow less secure apps** setting to **ON**.

Once this is done, you can send your message with `Send-MailMessage`. Here's a working example.

```
$MyEmail = "email@gmail.com"
$creds = get-credential -Message 'Enter your email credentials' -Username $MyEmail
$ServerParams = @{
    SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
    From = $MyEmail
    Port = 587
    UseSsl = $true
    Credential =  $creds
}

$MessageParams = @{
    'To' = "email@outlook.com"
    'Subject' = "Test E-Mail"
    'Body' = "FIRST EMAIL WITH POWERSHELL"
}

Send-MailMessage @ServerParams @MessageParams
```

**Bonus:** For a better readability and reusability, you can splat your parameters

(Reference:[About Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) )