# Sending SMTP Mail Through Gmail Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, email, smtp

I had this working at one time, but it stopped a while ago.  The password for the account is valid, and noting in my script has changed.

```
Send-MailMessage -From ESI-NIKE@gisx.com -Subject "Server ESI-NIKE Has Rebooted" -To Glen.krinsky@xerox.com -Attachments C:\1\Reboot\Previous5.txt -Body "ESI-NIKE has rebooted.  Please check the Event Log if this reboot is unexpected" -SmtpServer smtp.gmail.com -Port 587 -usessl -Credential (New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "zz.gms.service@gmail.com",(Get-Content -Path zz.gms.service@gmail.com.securestring | ConvertTo-SecureString))
```

Comment: What error(s) do you get?

Comment: Send-MailMessage : The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send-MailMessage on PowerShell does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54134963/send-mailmessage-on-powershell-does-not-work)

Look at my answer on that thread. It is specifically regarding how to make it work for gmail.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  I already enabled less secure apps.

Comment: @GlenKrinsky Just a thought. In the From field, it should be your gmail address and not anything else. Some mail server support setting anything there. Not gmail.

Answer (score 0):

Stop working for me too. for severail years I have been using PowerShell script to send emails via Gmail, rather Google G Suite, it just stopped working recently. Error is, SMTP requires a secure connection, but I am already using port 587, changed to port 465, still not working